# Latest earned tag badge doesn't update when I earn a new one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-badges, badge-progress

When you earn one tag badge, and then don't click "Track the next one" in the tag badge progress tracking box for a while, and then earn a *second* tag badge, that box continues to show "Congratulations, you earned [the same badge as before]", rather than updating to show that you've actually earned another tag badge since then.

For instance, right now [my profile on Puzzling SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5373/rand-althor?tab=topactivity) looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Even though I [earned the "enigmatic-puzzle" tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/enigmatic-puzzle?userid=5373) a few weeks ago and then [earned the "cipher" tag badge](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/badges/123/cipher?userid=5373) yesterday, my profile hasn't updated to show the new achievement.

I also didn't get the "cipher" tag badge until after the 3am watershed, even though tag badges usually appear as soon as I visit my profile after earning them (for instance, I earned the "tags" tag badge on meta.SFF.SE today the very instant I clicked on my own profile there after having become eligible for the badge). Even when I went to look at the list of my progress towards different tag badges on Puzzling, which I thought would jog the system into realising I'd actually earned the badge, "cipher" still showed up as 99/100 score even after I'd gone well past 100, until last night when the badge was finally awarded and "cipher" disappeared from my list of badges to track.

**TL;DR: if I don't click "Track the next one", my tag badges update slower than they should.**

It's a very unimportant bug, but there must be more people than just me who like to see the "Congratulations" thing there for a while and rest on their laurels before moving on to track their progress towards the *next* milestone.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't think it's a bug. If you want to track more badges, well... click the "Track next badge" button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The badge tracker is not a box to notify you of what your most recent badge you earned was, and it's perfectly possible to track a badge you're nowhere close to earning and have many different badges awarded to you during the time you're tracking that one. The badge tracker is explicitly set to a *single* badge and will continue tracking that badge until you decide to change it to something else, even if it just displays a congratulations message. What you earn in the meantime is irrelevant to it.

As far as tag badge awards go: they are still awarded only at 03:00 UTC with the rest of the processes that run at that time. The *only* exception is the tag badge you are currently tracking. If you have earned the tag badge you are currently tracking, then it will be instantly (or close to instantly) awarded by viewing your profile while you are currently eligible for that tag badge. There are some limitations on how often this works per day to prevent abuse, but I'm not familiar with the exact details.

Comment: "*The badge tracker is explicitly set to a single badge and will continue tracking that badge until you decide to change it to something else*" Thanks, that makes sense. I hadn't thought of it that way.