# congratulations for wrong badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, profile-page, badge-progress

I got a notification “You’ve earned the "modular-arithmetic" tag badge”. However, when I clicked on it, I got congratulations for the last tag (card-games), for which I’d already seen the congratulations; whereas to the right of the congratulations, it says “Newest: modular-arithmetic”. Here's a screenshot:

[image: badge congratulations]

Comment: Duplicate of [Latest earned tag badge doesn't update when I earn a new one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285191/latest-earned-tag-badge-doesnt-update-when-i-earn-a-new-one) (I had the same issue as you, but it's by design)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we enable tracking a badge statistic even if you already have the badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324682/can-we-enable-tracking-a-badge-statistic-even-if-you-already-have-the-badge) - related, track progress for same (multiple awarded) or next in series. Dupe suggestion offered to place another link in the banner.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You weren't tracking the modular-arithmetic tag badge there. You were tracking the card-games tag badge, and never clicked the "Track the next one" button to update it to track something else, so it's always just been displaying that congratulations message. You need to click the button to track another badge if you wish to see something else there.

The page is displaying items correctly. Your most recently tracked badge is completed. Your most recently earned badge is not necessarily the one you were tracking most recently - it's possible to earn other tag badges while tracking a different one (such as earning bronze tag badges while tracking progress towards a gold).