# "Congratulations!" and subsequent text is incorrectly positioned

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, badge-progress

I recently earned a tag badge. On my profile, the "Congratulations!" and subsequent text looks incorrectly positioned.

> [image]

Perhaps it is meant to look like this:

> [image]
>
> *(my mockup)*

Comment: It used to look like that before: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344322/295232